# Use renewenvironment to replace an environment with nothing

Tags: pdftex, environments, overleaf

I have a latex document with several `textblock*` environments that look like:

```
\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(8cm,5cm) 
%
\end{textblock*}
```

or

```
\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(8.50cm,5.00cm) 
%
\end{textblock*}
```

To remove these parts with "nothing", I do this (which works partly):

```
\renewenvironment{textblock*}[9]{%
  \empty%
}{%
  \empty%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}
```

Without using the `[9]` above, I noticed that the resulting document still shows the options `11cm(8cm,5cm)`. If I use `[1]`, the `11cm` is not shown anymore, but still the part `(8cm,5cm)` appears. Even using `[9]` (9 seems to be the maximum), I could not get rid of everything as still some parts such as `cm)` are shown in the text. Any idea how I can get rid of the part `{11cm}(8cm,5cm)` completely?

Comment: `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{textblock*}{m r()}{}{}`?

Comment: Do you wish TeX to treat the "body"/content of the environment as if it was not wrapped between directives for beginning/ending the environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the environment to do nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textpos}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{textblock*}{+b}{}{}

\begin{document}

A paragraph.

\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(8cm,5cm) 
Something here
\end{textblock*}

Another paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just uncommenting the redefinition will produce

[image]

In case you want instead to produce the text in the environment, do

```
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{textblock*}{}{mr()}{}{}
```